# Occasional no response from Selenium Grid server - any theories?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, grid, selenium-grid

While locally we're having no problems, on a virtual server we're running Jenkins which kicks off Selenium Grid to execute some of our tests.

**Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. -> No response from server**

Every so often, usually on a click event, I get a test failing with a large Selenium error.  I'm having no luck reproducing this locally, and am sort of at a loss as to how to proceed in fixing it.  I'll include the error below:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. -> No response from server for url http://vm-selgrid3:5555/wd/hub/session/0894b06e-6e4f-46bc-ba82-f72a75deeb8d/element/12/click

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url http://vm-selgrid3:5555/wd/hub/session/0894b06e-6e4f-46bc-ba82-f72a75deeb8d/element/12/click
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.PageFactory.ProxiedWebElementInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IWrapsElementProxy.Click()
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions on where you have the grid running?  Perhaps is the driver crashing and restarting and this is trying to execute when it is in a non running state?

Comment: @DanSnell we did some debugging and turns out that our version of java on the server is 32 bit.  We've upgraded to 64-bit and the errors have reduced by 95%, but it's still happening occasionally :/

Comment: maybe the grid is overloaded. How many browsers can run in parallel at a time in the remote system eg. the configuration of the grid. Try to reduce that number and check if the problem still occurs. Also you can try to update the version of the grid. And are you using the grid as a plugin of jenkins or as a standalone installation which you just trigger through Jenkins using e.g. command line

Comment: @chesthar this was 8 years ago now, but I do remember sliding the number down to 1 and it'd still happen occasionally.  Was running separately and Jenkins would trigger it remotely.